# Can we use Eventloop(python) with any of the Async libraries in flask to integrate async task handling?

Tags: python, flask, python-asyncio, event-loop

I need to use Eventloop(in python) with any of the Async libraries in python like Sanic, Asyncio, Quart etc, so that I can use the task queue method to execute the tasks as I want to return the response as soon as possible when the URL is visited and then execute the task while it is in the eventloop.
I tried using Celery which uses celery-worker as task queue but in that we need to maintain another worker side by side and I want to avoid this.

So, I was thinking of using Eventloop with any of the Async libraries.
If anyone knows about which library is best for integrating Eventloop and how can we use it in that library.

Comment: Why are you opposed to a separate process? The whole point is that your asynchronous task shouldn't contend with your request handlers for resources.

Comment: Yes , you are right . But how can i achieve this , "As soon as a request is fired , then the server returns a response as soon as possible and then execute the ling running task". I tried using various methods to this and I thought that there might be some Async library to fulfill this task.If you know , then please could you suggest me.